# Output the average in C programming

Tags: c, average

I wrote a program that has you input numbers and output the average. It isn't outputting the exact answer sometimes and I'm not sure why. For example when I input 1, 2, 10, -3, it outputs 2, but it should output 2.50. Also, is there a way to get it to break out of the loop by inputting a letter such as N instead of 0? Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int nA = 1;
    int nSum = 0;
    int input = 0;
    double dAvg = 0;
    int nums = 0;
    printf("enter numbers to find the average\n");
    printf("enter 0 to quit.\n");
    while (nA !=0) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        nA = input;
        nSum+=nA;
        if (nA !=0) {
            nums = nums + 1;
        }
        dAvg = nSum / nums;
    }   
    printf("your average is %lf\n", dAvg);    
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You should use `double` for the data type of `nSum` and `nums` rather than `int`. Integer division truncates the result. For example, the result of `10/3` will be truncated from `3.3333...` to `3`.

Comment: if the first number is 0, your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: What average do you require - mean, mode or median?

Comment: Thanks that worked! Still, is there a way to break out of the loop by using a letter instead of 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It isn't outputting the exact answer sometimes and I'm not sure why.

This line of code is the culprit:

```
dAvg = nSum / nums
```

When you input 1, 2, 10, -3 you should get 2.5, but the decimal portion of the result is getting truncated.  Instead, you should do `double` division:

```
dAvg = double(nSum) / nums
```

> Also, is there a way to get it to break out of the loop by inputting a letter such as N instead of 0?

Yes, there is.  You can use the C function `scanf_s`:

```
char input; // use a char instead of an int
do {
    scanf_s("%c", input, 1);
    if (input == 'N') {
        break;
    }

    nA = input - '0'; // convert char input to int value
    nSum+=nA;
    nums = nums + 1;
    dAvg = nSum / nums;
}
```

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with char. Do I put that inside of the while loop?

Comment: Replace your `int input` with `char input` and replace your `while` loop with the `do` loop I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You divide integers, you should do a double division:

```
dAvg = nSum / (double)nums;
```

Comment: Ok, the new version works! Yay! But, I'm still wondering if it is possible to break out of the loop by using a letter instead of a number...

Comment: @Timmy Yes, that's possible. Check the return value of `scanf`. Look at the documentation for `scanf` to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the division arguments as `double`:

```
dAvg = (double) nSum / nums;
```

This had to be done because as `nSum` and `nums` both are `int`, they undergo *integer division*, that is the decimal part is truncated or the division operator returns an `int`. Hence, to avoid this, we have to explicitly cast `double` in the division.

Answer (score 0):

The division operator gets two `int`s as operands and hence it returns an `int`. The result gets implicitly converted to a `float` by the addition of decimal points. If you want `float` divisions, you should give at least one of the two operands to the division operator as `float`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int count = 0, nSum = 0;
   char input = 0;
   double dAvg;
   while(scanf("%c", &input) != -1) { // while not error
      if(input == 'N') break; // go out of loop, you can do it another way:
      // while (scanf("%c", &input) != -1 && input != 'N') {
      if(input != 0) { // If you don't want to count zeros
         nSum += input - '0';
         ++count; // increment by one
      }
   }
   // Here you can check internal errors
   if(count != 0) dAvg = nSum * 1.0 / count;
   printf("%f\n", dAvg); // print double
```

}

Internally type char is no more than simple number(0-255 if it is unsigned). All simbols is actually there codes, i.e. numbers too. That is why you can work with char as with numbers:

```
char a = 'c';
int b = a + 4;
```